# Prove that $\sup (-A) = -\inf A$

Tags: calculus

> Prove that $\sup (-A) = -\inf A$. Note: Assume $A$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and define $\alpha A = \{\alpha A \mid a \in A\}$.

I said let $x \in A$. Then if $y = \inf{A}$, we have $y \leq x \implies -y \geq -x$. Therefore $-\inf{A}$ is an upper bound for $-A$. Then how do I show a contradiction to $-\inf A > \sup (-A)$?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little fussy, but we just use the definitions. So, step by step:

if $s=\sup (-A),\ $ then

1). it is an upper bound for $-A$

2). If $x$ is any other upper bound, then $s<x$.

Now you want to show that $-s= \inf A$. So check the conditions:

1). $-s$ is a lower bound for $A$: this follows because $s\geq a$ for all $a\in -A\Rightarrow -s\leq -a$. But $a\in -A\Leftrightarrow -a\in A$, so in fact $-s$ is a lower bound for $A$.

2). Now suppose $y$ is another lower bound for $A$. Then $-y$ is an upper bound for $-A$ (why?) and hence $s<-y$. But then $-s>y$ which finishes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

You've shown $-\inf A\geq\sup(-A)$. For the reverse inequality, just employ the same strategy. Let $x\in A$. Then, $-x\in -A$. Hence, $-x\leq \sup(-A)\implies x\geq-\sup(-A)$. Since this holds for all $x\in A$, it follows that $\inf A\geq-\sup(-A)\implies-\inf A\leq\sup(-A)$.

Comment: Does this also hold if $A$ is empty?

Comment: If $A=\emptyset$, the statement holds trivially.